# Add xcframework to iOS part of Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, xcframework

I'm developing a Flutter Plugin which needs a C++ plugin (available as local `xxx.xcframework`) for its iOS native part to work.
I have already managed to add this xcframework to the native part of a Flutter **app**, but im struggeling to add it to the Flutter **plugin**.

The main problem for me is figuring out how and where to add the header files describing the functions in `xxx.xcframework` so that they can be used in Swift.

I have tried adding the import directives to the umbrella header of the iOS plugin part, but this only resulted in other problems, namely:

1. This file gets regenerated when `pod install` is run
2. Xcode reports "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'xxx'" (setting "Allow Non-Modular includes in Framework Modules" under Build Settings did not help either)

This leads me to believe that I have to add a custom header myself.

I am by no means an expert in iOS development/Xcode, so any help is greatly appreciated.